# Remove hidden tags from php json data for android application

Tags: php, android, json, special-characters, hidden-characters

I have created json format data using php and it's showing like

```
"address":"8th Floor, \u200bTower  EN27  Sector 9  Salt Lake City  \u2013 700081  India",
```

I have used `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` and trying to remove using `str_replace` and `preg_replace` as well but unable to remove  **\u200b** characters.

If I echo my address value it's showing fine

*8th Floor, ​Tower
EN27
Sector 9
Salt Lake City – 700081
India*

One of my friend fetching my json data in his android application.

Please suggest me how to fix this issue.thanks

Comment: \u200b is a zero width space so depending on where to are getting your data from you could trim or replace it before it enters the json

Comment: Not working.... already checked.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know how to avoid those unicodes in the Result Json (PHP). But, I would like to suggest you to let android handle this.

```
txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
txtResult.setText(Html.fromHtml("8th Floor, \u200bTower  EN27  Sector 9  Salt Lake City  \u2013 700081  India"));
```

The Unicode can be removed by setting to the textview with the help of `HTML` class.

[image: Here is the sample textview]

I have tested this also. It is working really fine.